# How to find the documents which have an empty array in them in MongoDB using Mongoose in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the 'QAns' model, I want to load all the documents in which the 'Answers' field is an empty array using mongoose in node.js. I am using MongoDB Atlas for storing my data. This is my schema for the database:

```
const QuestAnsSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String,
    answers: [{
        text: String,
        author: String
   }]
});
```

This is the data in the MongoDB database.

```
{
     "_id":{"$oid":"5ee1f235a1e9870daca7d5e9"},
     "text":"Question 1",
     "author":"5ee1b8ebdbf91b23a808d417",
     "answers":[],
     "__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
},
{
     "_id":{"$oid":"5ee1f235885770darrr7f449"},
     "text":"Question 2",
     "author":"5ee1b8ebdbf9o2w3a808d417",
     "answers":[],
     "__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

Both the documents have the 'answers' field empty in them but assuming there would be some documents with a non-empty 'answers' field how will I load the ones with no answers field?

I have tried this code but it gives a 'Bad Request' error:

```
router.get('/questions', (req, res) => {
    QAns.find({answers: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }).then(( err, result) => {
        if(err)  return res.sendStatus(400);

        res.render('questions',{ result });

        console.log(result);
    });

})
```

- QAns is the model name, answers is the array field
- 'questions' is the ejs file which will display those documents after they are loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$size` operator to fetch all the documents where `answers` array is of length zero.

```
QAns.find({
  answers: { $size: 0 } 
})
```

[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#op._S_size) operator is used to query an array by number of elements.

### Edit:

To select all the documents where `answers` array is not empty, use `$not` operator along with `$size` operator.

Following query will select all the documents where `answers` array is not empty

```
QAns.find({
  answers: {
    $not: { $size: 0 }
  }
})
```

[$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) operator performs a logical NOT operation on the specified `<operator-expression>` and selects the documents that do not match the `<operator-expression>`

P.S. Above query will also return those documents where `answers` field is not present

Comment: Thanks, it worked! How do I do this for a non-empty answers field?

Comment: you mean you want to find those documents where answers array is not empty? If yes then see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

`$exists` works great for your needs, you just have a syntax error in your query coming from your `$ne`.

It's unclear if you want documents with answers or without so ill provide both options:

1. this will provide documents without the answer field:

```
QAns.find({answers: { $exists: false })
```

2. this will provice documents with at least one answer in the answers field:

```
QAns.find({"answers.0": { $exists: true } })
```

3. this will provide documents with `answers=[]`

```
QAns.find({"optOuts.0": {$exists: false}, optOuts: {$exists: true}})
```

Or as Yousaf suggjested:

```
QAns.find({"answers": { $size: 0 } })
```

Comment: OP wants to fetch documents which have empty answers array, not those documents where `answers` field doesn't exists or those where there's atleast one item in `answers` array.

Comment: I'm not so sure you're right as the explanation is poorly worded and the code snipper he posted has `$ne: []`.

Comment: _I want to load all the documents in which the 'Answers' field is an empty array_